# c++ binary operator warning

Tags: c++, binary, bitwise-operators

Could somebody explain some weird warning behavior.

I get that it is implicitly converting to ints.
But why are the first 2 lines ok? When the ~ operator is used, the compiler starts throwing warnings. If it is converting to ints, shouldn't it also warn on the first 2 lines?

Ubuntu 16.04 g++5.4

```
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

// g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wconversion main.cpp -o main

// warning: conversion to ‘uint8_t {aka unsigned char}’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]

int main()
{
    uint8_t a = 0x00U;
    uint8_t b = 0x01U;

    a = a | b;  // no warning
    a |= b;     // no warning
    a = ~b;     // warning
    a = a | ~b; // warning
    a |= ~b;    // warning
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would have expect warning also for `a = a | b;`...

Answer (score 4):

When a variable or value smaller than `int` is involved in an arithmetic expression, it is [implicitly converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to an `int`. For some types the compiler can do another implicit conversion back to the original type, but in others that's not possible without loss of data.

Take for example your unsigned byte value `0x00`. When converted to an `int` it becomes `0x00000000`. Bitwise complement turns it into `0xffffffff`, which can't be converted back to an unsigned byte without losing data.

And it's especially bad for values like that, because as an `int` the value `0xffffffff` is equal to `-1` (read about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) to learn why), which can't really be converted to an *unsigned* byte cleanly.

Therefore, and to also not risk overflows (unless that's wanted) I suggest you do all integer arithmetic using `int` (or `unsigned int`). Then don't convert to smaller types until you absolutely need it.

Comment: As long as only binary operators involving no shifting are used there is no data loss or possible overflow though. There is just extra-data manipulated before being dropped. So in his case using uint8_t is absolutely ok.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 possibilities if you don't want any warning:

Solution 1:

```
int main()
{
    uint8_t a = 0x00U;
    uint8_t b = 0x01U;

    a = a | b;
    a |= b;
    a = static_cast<uint8_t>(~b);
    a = a | static_cast<uint8_t>(~b);
    a |= static_cast<uint8_t>(~b);
    return 0;
}
```

Solution 2:

```
int main()
{
    uint32_t a = 0x00U;
    uint32_t b = 0x01U;

    a = a | b;
    a |= b;
    a = ~b;
    a = a | ~b;
    a |= ~b;
    return 0;
}
```

You could think the second one is less efficient because it uses bigger numbers, that's actually false. In the first solution the implicit conversions to 32-bit numbers because of `operator ~` cost some memory and performance. The second solution should actually be more efficient. In general you should use (at least) uint32_t and use masks if you want the 8-bit value:

```
uint32_t value = 0xFFFFFFFF;
uint32_t mask = 0xFFu;

value &= mask; // Now value is 0x000000FF
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that using 32-bit increases efficiency.   That is compiler-dependent.   Not all compilers are optimised around 32-bit integral types.

Comment: The compiler doesn't, but your hardware is generally more optimized for 32-64-bit integer manipulation so there are strong chances that on the CPU everything turns to 32/64 bit at some time.

Comment: There is also real-world hardware that is not optimised for 32 or 64 bit integers.   That's one of the reasons (there are others) that not all compilers work with 32 bit.

Comment: Yep I had made the hypothesis that this was a classic x86/amd64 system.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is smart:
    uint8_t a = 0x00U;
    uint8_t b = 0x01U;

```
a = a | b;  // no warning
a |= b;     // no warning
```

given two 8 bit values, `|` cannot set a bit higher than 8.  So no bits are lost when converting back to 8 bits.

The result of `a|b` is an `int` regardless, but the compiler also knows it is an 8 bit clean int.

The result of `~a` is *not* an 8 bit clean int -- `a` is converted to a (maybe 32 bit) int, then all bits are inverted (setting high bits).  So if converted back to 8 bits some set high order bits are lost.

This is true in all of these cases:

```
a = ~b;     // warning
a = a | ~b; // warning
a |= ~b;    // warning
```

after `a=~b`, `a==~b` is not true.  In the `a=a|~b` case, if we stored the result `auto c=a|~b;`, then did `a=c`, `a==c` wouldn't be true afterwards.  The `|=` case has a similar observation complicated by self modification.